# How can i catch and return json if user emal is duplicate

Tags: php, laravel

i want to return a response if there is a duplicate user email in database

i already try to checking the email with clause "where", but the return is to the views/welcome.blade.php

i want the json response to be 
{
  success: false,
  error: "email already registered"
}

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    // VALIDATION FIELD
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'          => 'required',
        'company_name'  => 'required',
        'email'         => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password'      => 'required|min:8'
    ]);

    try {

        // DATA REQUEST
        $data = [
            'name'          => $request->input('name'),
            'company_name'  => $request->input('company_name'),
            'email'         => $request->input('email'),
            'password'      => Hash::make($request->input('password'))
        ];

        User::create($data);

        // IF SUCCESS RETURN SUCCESS => TRUE
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data'  => $data
        ]);

        if(User::where('email', '=', $data->email )->exists()){
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'error'  => 'Email already registered, try another email'
            ]);
        }else{
            // CREATE DATA
            User::create($data);

            // IF SUCCESS RETURN SUCCESS => TRUE
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'data'  => $data
            ]);
        }


    }catch (\Throwable $e) {
        // IF SUCCESS RETURN SUCCESS => False
        return response()->json([
            'success'   => false,
            'error'     => "Error On Line {$e->getLine()}, <br>Message:<br>{$e->getMessage()}",
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Laravel 5 :

Use below manually validation process :

```php
        // use Validator facade after namespace & replace below line of code 

        //$this->validate($request, [
        //    'email'         => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users'
        //]); 

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email'         => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = $validator->errors();
            if ($errors->has('email')) {
               
               # Return json response with first error.
               return response()->json([
                  'success' => false,
                  'error'   => $errors->first('email')
               ]);

            }
        }
```

Visit more Ref to : [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators)

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply catch error and filter it with conditions like I did below.

```js
.catch((e)=>{ 
      if(e.name==="MongoError" && e.code===11000 && e.keyPattern.email) return res.status(500).json({success:"false",message:"Error!!!Account with this email already exists"});  
      if(e.name==="MongoError" && e.code===11000 && e.keyPattern.mobile) return res.status(500).json({success:"false",message:"Error!!!Duplicate mobile number"});  
      res.status(500).json({success:"false",message:e.message});
    })
```

Note: If it is just email, no need for keyPattern but if other fields that require unique values like mobile no. is present, include them as such.